# How to check programmatically if the Ethernet cable is plugged in?

Tags: networking, command-line, network-interface, ethernet

As you know, in Windows when we plug in the network cable, the network symbol will change to another status.

How can I know whether the cable is plugged in or not via the command prompt in Linux?

Answer (score 18):

The 2 methods I've seen used predominately are to use `ethtool` or to manually parse the contents of `/sys`.

#### ethtool

For example if your interface is `eth0` you can query it using `ethtool` and then parse for the line, "Link detected".

*Example*

```
$ sudo ethtool eth0
Settings for eth0:
    Supported ports: [ TP ]
    Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                            100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
    Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
    Advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                            100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
    Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
    Speed: 100Mb/s
    Duplex: Full
    Port: Twisted Pair
    PHYAD: 1
    Transceiver: internal
    Auto-negotiation: on
    Supports Wake-on: pumbag
    Wake-on: g
    Current message level: 0x00000001 (1)
    Link detected: yes
```

Specifically this command:

```
$ ethtool eth0 | grep "Link"
Link detected: yes
```

If it were down it would say no.

#### Using /sys

Again assuming we're interested in `eth0`, you can manually parse the contents of [`/sys/class/net/`](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/ABI/testing/sysfs-class-net) and then `eth0` for your device. There are 2 files under this directory that will tell you the status of whether the link is active or not, `carrier` and `operstate`:

When the wire is connected these 2 files will present as follows:

```
$ cat /sys/class/net/eth0/{carrier,operstate}
1
up
```

When the wire is disconnected these 2 files will present as follows:

```
$ cat /sys/class/net/eth0/{carrier,operstate}
0
down
```

#### References

- [How to detect the physical connected state of a network cable/connector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/808560/how-to-detect-the-physical-connected-state-of-a-network-cable-connector)

Answer (score 5):

Use [**mii-tool**](http://sourceforge.net/projects/net-tools/) ([man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/mii-tool.8.html)):

```
# mii-tool em1
em1: negotiated 100baseTx-FD flow-control, link ok
```

There is also [**nmcli**](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/NetworkManager/nmcli) from NetworkManager:

```
$ nmcli -f capabilities.carrier-detect,capabilities.speed device show em1
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            yes
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     100 Mb/s
```

<sup>* `device` can be shorten to `d`</sup>

Comment: Better solution, but not all interfaces support MII inquiries.